# Fields pending deletion error when disabling comment module

Tags: 8

I tried to disable the comment module but got the following error `comment: Fields pending deletion`. I deleted all my comment content and fields, but the error keeps appearing and I can't disable the module. Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did some batch operations or import. Running cron could solve the issue, or run the following command in drush:

```
drush php-eval 'field_purge_batch(1000);'
```

Change the '1000' value to larger numbers if you did for example an import of more nodes.